# Pagination Dot animation in react-native-snap-carousel?

Tags: javascript, react-native, pagination, react-native-snap-carousel

I never made any animations, and i am new to javascript. So what i want to ask is even possible to make some simple animation for example like fade in fade out of active and inactive dots in  `react-native-snap-carousel`? 
I am using my custom dots :

https://streamable.com/snah0

Can i do some animations for dots similar to this one, don't mind the line tho, i dont need it. All i interested is the smooth fade in fade out animation of the dot: 
[image: Example]